# the fastest way to parse large file (~2 Gb) delimited with Tab

Tags: c++, file, io

Please, guide me: is there more efficient way to perform such tasks:

1. Read Key-Value pairs from the first tab delimited file into map container
2. While reading from the second tab delimited file (Key-Value pairs), writing to the third one

It took 3700 seconds to perform these two steps for fname1 and fname2 with 7,000,000 lines.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
string col1;
int x;
map<string, int> m;
ifstream is1(fname1, ios::in | ios::binary);
ifstream is2(fname2, ios::in | ios::binary);
ofstream os3(fname3, ios::out | ios::binary);
if (is1.is_open())
{
    while (is1 >> col1 >> x)
    {
        m[col1] = x;
    }
    is.close();
}
if (is2.is_open() && os3.is_open())
{
    while (is2 >> col1 >> x)
    {
        if (m.count(col1) > 0)
            x += m[col1];
        os3 << col1 << "\t" << x << endl;
    }
    is2.close();
    os3.close();
}
```

What did I do wrong? Is there more efficient way to perform such tasks?
Or file I/O are a bottlenecks in the most cases?

UPDATED: Here I put two implementations of the same algorithm. The main question: why pythonic version works **faster**? I've decided to switch towards C++, because I've heard it provide faster code. Was I wrong ?

fname1, fname2 - input. fname3 - desired output.

fname1:

col1 col2 col3

1 1 1

2 2 2

fname2:

col1 col2 col3

1 1 2

3 3 3

fname3:

col1 col2 col3

1 1 3

2 2 2

3 3 3

```
def merge_two_files(fname1, fname2, fname3):
    fout=open(fname3,'w')
    fin1=open(fname1)
    d1=dict()
    for line in fin1:
        l=line.strip().split('\t')
        key='\t'.join(l[0:2])
        d1[key] = float(l[2])
    fin1.close()
    d2=dict()
    fin2=open(fname2)
    for line in fin2:
        l=line.strip().split('\t')
        key='\t'.join(l[0:2])
        d2[key] = float(l[2])
    fin2.close()
    for e in d1.viewkeys() & d2.viewkeys():
        line_out='\t'.join([e,'{:.2f}'.format(d1[e]+d2[e])])
        fout.write(line_out+'\n')
    for e in d1.viewkeys() - (d1.viewkeys() & d2.viewkeys())
        line_out='\t'.join([e,'{:.2f}'.format(d1[e])])
        fout.write(line_out+'\n')
    for e in d2.viewkeys() - (d1.viewkeys() & d2.viewkeys())
        line_out='\t'.join([e,'{:.2f}'.format(d2[e])])
        fout.write(line_out+'\n')

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unordered_map < string, float > map1, map2 ;
    set < string > s1, s2, both ;
    string col1, col2, key, fname1, fname2, fname3 ;
    float col3 ;
    ifstream f1 ( fname1, ios::in | ios::binary) ;
    ifstream f2 ( fname2, ios::in | ios::binary) ;
    ofstream f3 ( fname3, ios::out | ios::binary) ;

    if ( f1.is_open() ) {
        while ( f1 >> col1 >> col2 >> col3 )
        key= col1 + "\t" + col2 ;
        map1.insert(make_pair(key,col3)) ;
        s1.insert(key) ;
    }
    f1.close()
    if ( f2.is_open() ) {
        while ( f2 >> col1 >> col2 >> col3 ) {
        key= col1 + "\t" + col2 ;
        map2.insert(make_pair(key,col3)) ;
        s2.insert(key) ;
        }
    }
    f2.close() ;

    set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(),
                     s2.begin(), s2.end(),
                     inserter(both, both.begin())) ;
    if ( f3.is_open() ) {
        for ( const auto& e : both ) {
            f3 << e << "\t" << map1.at(e) + map2.at(e) << "\n" ;
        }
        for ( const auto& kv : map1 ) {
            if ( both.count(kv.first) ) continue ;
            f3 << kv.first << "\t" << kv.second << "\n" ;
        }
        for ( const auto& kv : map2 ) {
            if ( both.count(kv.first) ) continue ;
            f3 << kv.first << "\t" << kv.second << "\n" ;
        }
    }
    f3.close() ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using an optimized build?  Do you have enough RAM to hold all that content in memory without using the paging file?

Comment: Replace `endl` with `'\n'`.  `endl` flushes the file each time and is very inefficient.

Comment: I've replaced `endl` with `'\n'`, but the program accelerated a little, but thank you anyway - I've got more familiar with streams.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, `-O3` or `-Ofast`. I guess, yes. How can I check with PowerShell: how much RAM available before OS starts to use paging file?

Answer (score 1):

At least in the limit of large number of different keys in these files (I assume you come close enough here), the limiting factor will be the `map` key lookup, not the IO. Looking up a key in a `std::map` has time complexity `O(ln n)` where `n` is the number of different keys in the container.

Use `std::unordered_map` which has amortized `O(1)` key lookup time on average.

Use a profiler to tell you where most of the time is spent, before you begin optimizing on wrong assumptions. Do the same in this case as well to verify whether I am correct.

Comment: Thank you for the rapid answer. Your idea is great. In fact, I do not need sorted keys to look up for the key. But the program accelerated a little bit. I've implemented the same algorithm with Python: it took 195 seconds versus 1152 seconds with C++. I do not understand why?

Comment: @IvanVodopyanov If you changed to the `unordered_map` then in terms of average asymptotic time complexity there is nothing more to improve really. The rest comes down to improving the linear time factor. ThomasMatthews gave a more comprehensive list of possible such bottlenecks. Use a profiler (e.g. `perf` on linux) to figure out in which of the categories your program spends most time. You could also add the python version to the question, so that we can verify whether the programs indeed do the same.

Comment: @IvanVodopyanov You could also add a python script (or other) generating the input files, then anyone would potentially be able to benchmark/profile it themselves (if anyone has time to do so)

Answer (score 1):

### The Bottlenecks

Your bottlenecks are 1) file I/O and 2) format conversion.  A file may require overhead such as spinning up (hard drives), seek time and actual read time.

### Streaming the Data

Whether the file is located on a Flash drive or a hard drive, streaming the data is most efficient (that is, keep the data flowing).  For example, reading 1k of data in 1 transaction is more efficient than reading 1k of data in 1k transactions.  Your most efficient method here is to read large quantities into memory.  You may want to check your OS to see if it supports memory mapping.

### Converting the Data

Your next bottleneck is parsing and converting the data from textual to internal numeric format.  It takes time.  To speed this up, have your data written in a binary (internal) representation.  This may not be possible due to Endianess or floating point issues.

### Storing the Data

I guess the next bottleneck is to store the internal formatted data into a data structure.  For key, value, pairs, you may want to use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.  If you don't care about search time, you may want to create a `struct` with the values and store into an array (or `std::vector` if the quantity is not known at compile time).

### Profiling

The best way to find out where your bottlenecks are is to *profile*.  Run your application 1E6 repetitions and take the average (you may need to run 1E9 to get better accuracy).  Search the internet for "Benchmarking C++ programs".  Benchmarking will show you how to get better results.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. I did not understand 'Storing the Data' section. Of course, I do care about search time, so you've advised me **not to use** `struct` and `vector`?

Comment: All depends.  Search the internet for "database theory index tables".  A `struct` or `class` is good at modeling the data.  You can place all the data into a `vector`, but unsorted vectors don't have good search times.  In the database arena, all the data is placed into a table (a.k.a. vector), then index tables are built.  The index tables (`std::map`) contain the search key and the index into the `vector`.  The index table provides faster search times, than resorting the vector each time.

Comment: If you don't know the amount of data at compile time, another bottleneck will be expanding of the database (`vector` or array).  The vector will allocate room for X items.  When you `push_back()` after the X item, the vector needs to expand.  Expanding involves allocating new, larger, memory, the copying the old memory to the new memory; all taking up time.  You can reduce this by having your data source specify the number of records in the header section of the data file (if possible).

Comment: I have often sped up programs by block reading from the file into a *buffer*.  The blocks would be around 1MB.  Another layer of efficiency is to use multiple buffers and threads.  The reader thread reads a buffer, then signals the computation thread.  The reader then starts on the next buffer.  This allows the reader to *continuously* operate, which the computation thread executes.  The amount and sizes of the buffers would need to be adjusted to the optimal efficiency in your situation (one size does not fit all).  Search the web for "double buffering multiple buffers"